# Cloud functions or local server as fulfillment?

Tags: actions-on-google, google-home, google-smart-home

Can anyone tell me about the pros and cons of using Google's cloud function as fulfillment over a local server. We have a local server available, but we can't decide which to go for. I am currently creating a smarthome action and no matter what, the Google cloud functions would need to make a call to my server to be able to control my devices.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read about [asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). Avoid asking questions that start with "Can anyone" as the answer may be "Yes" with no further information provided. Opinion based question or software recommendation questions are also problematic.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually use the [Local Home SDK](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/concepts/local) to enable local fulfillment for your integration. For EXECUTE intents targeted at locally-controllable devices, the command will be routed over the LAN from a Google Nest device.